# Let's clean up these very-specific Go tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I just came across [computer-go](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-go), having already noted a not-overly-populated [computer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer).  Should [computer-go](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-go) be eliminated, with those questions being tagged with both [computer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer) and [go](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go)?  If not, aren't we setting ourselves up for other game-specific computer tags?

I then came across [9x9](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/9x9), which has three questions, all also tagged [go](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go).  Should we eliminate this tag?  I assume we don't want to also use it for Tafl variants played on a 9x9 board.

(I suspect there are many more tags that assume the question is about Go.  I have already proposed a tag-wiki revision for [handicap](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handicap) to make it not just about Go.  I haven't reviewed every tag by any means.)

Comment: I've created a [tag:computer-AI] tag to replace some of these [tag:computer-go] tags, my logic being one of the main topics is beating/playing computers and that can be shared by many board games.

Comment: I think the 9x9 tag is a good tag, maybe it should be renamed [go-9x9]

Comment: Adding to your list, [tag:invasion] and [tag:extension]

Answer (score 4):

I think the edits you made for [handicap](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handicap) are very good. Other tags (e.g. [invasion](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/invasion), [extension](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extension), [9x9](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/9x9)) are, I think, tags that should be kept, but perhaps with a "go-" prefix added on. There are also Japanese Go term tags (e.g. [joseki](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joseki)) that are probably fine as is.

Comment: If they're meaningful sub-divisions of the "Go" space then I'm fine with keeping them, but they should have "go" in their names as you propose.  Other games have extensions, handicaps, and different board sizes, after all.

Comment: The biggest reason I would see for a prefix is if there's risk of another game having that as a name (Invasion seems particularly prone). I think the handicap tag is good being general, but I don't foresee the extension tag really causing difficulty. Stack Overflow has tags such as "gui" or "plot" which are used almost exclusively in language-specific questions. If another game with extensions wants to use the extensions tag, then we should generalize the tag wiki rather than create new game-extension tags.

Comment: When I saw "extension" in the tag list I assumed it was a synonym for "expansion" (and briefly wondered why it was singular).  Since I am not a Go player I had no idea it was a Go term.

Comment: @MonicaCellio But that is easily fixed by a tag wiki, rather than a tag prefix.

Comment: Ok.  The wiki excerpt should probably start with "In Go, ..."; you want it to be easy to notice when people are typing tag names.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yeah, I'm trying to hit all the Go tags to make sure that's the case.